# Access file on mac share using NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I need to access a shared file hosted on a mac shared folder, However when I directly pass the path to the `NSFileManager` it reports as file does not exist.

```
NSURL *fileURLPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",IP,PATH ]];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[fileURLPath path]])
{
}
```

I believe it's due to the authentication . How should handle or pass the credentials using the `NSFileManager` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to see what your resulting URL looks like. If I understand your variable naming correctly, you're creating an invalid URL. If IP is `@"127.0.0.1"` and path is `@"foo"`, the resulting URL will be `file://127.0.0.1,foo`, which isn't a valid URL. `NSFileManager` expects a file URL pointing to a descendant directory of the mount point. This implies that the share has to be mounted. Authentication is not required.